# Insert a file path string into SQL database via C# code

Tags: c#, sql, linq

In SQL:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblFiles]
           ([FullFilePath]
           ,[LastModified])
     VALUES
           ('P:\test\test.csv', 
           null)
```

This will store the full path in the database :)
However, I need to do this in code.

```
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DatabaseHelper.ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand( "stpInsertFile", connection);
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@filepath", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar));
    command.Parameters["@filepath"].Value = article.FullFilePath;

    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter( "@LastModified", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime));
    command.Parameters["@LastModified"].Value = article.LastModified;


    int newArticleID = Convert.ToInt32((decimal)command.ExecuteNonQuery());

    command.Dispose();
    connection.Close();
    connection.Dispose();

    return newArticleID;
```

With this all I get is 'P' in the full path column.
So I tried using LINQ and got the same result.

```
   public int InsertArticleUsingLINQ(tblFile article) {
            DataClassesDataContext context = new DataClassesDataContext();

                tblFile newFileEntry = new tblFile();
                newFileEntry.FullFilePath = article.FullFilePath;
                newFileEntry.LastModified = article.LastModified;
                context.tblFiles.InsertOnSubmit(newFileEntry);
                context.SubmitChanges();

                return newFileEntry.ID;

        }
```

I'm not doing anything with the string before passing it to the database insert functions. I read that you need to escape the backslash but it seems to be escaping on the quote. Also read that you need an @ symbol before the sql but how do you add this to a parameter?

Comment: what does 'stpInsertFile' do?

Comment: What value is article.FullFilePath holding? Maybe it goes wrong before you insert it.

Comment: You may need to add quotes when you set `command.Parameters["@filepath"].Value`

Comment: It doesn't like single quotes or double quotes using ADO. However the LINQ code does work now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**warning: since you didn't share the stored procedure code this is just a wild guess.**

did you set the size of the `@filePath` parameter in the definition of your stored procedure?

if you declare it as:

```
create procedure stpInsertFile
    @filepath     varchar,
    @LastModified datetime
as
...
```

then you parameter is created as `varchar(1)` because of the default behaviour of varchar datatype and that would produce the result you get.
please check [reference documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for char and varchar datatype on ms website.

Comment: Yep that was it. An easy mistake to make?

Answer (score 1):

if  `stpInsertFile` is a Stored Procedure you will have to set in your code:

```
...
 command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

else you have to set the query string in your command:

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand( "INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblFiles] ([FullFilePath] [LastModified])  VALUES  (@filepath,@LastModified)", connection);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Of the above options, the ADO code did not copy the full path, even with manually adding quotes. All I ever got was one character in the database.

On further inspection, the parameter was of type Varchar(1) !!! I changed this to Varchar(255) an it worked.

Note, the LINQ to SQL function did insert the full path as this was not using the Stored Procedure.

Apologies for the mistake.